# Show that the set of non-decreasing functions on [0,1] is a closed convex subset of $C^r$[0,1]

Tags: analysis

We are given a set $D$ of non-decreasing real functions on the interval $[0,1]$, meaning $f\in D$ implies $f(x)\leq f(y)$ whenever $x\leq y$. We are now asked to show that $D$ is a closed convex subset of $C^r[0,1]$.

I'm not used to these kinds of computations. My attempt was to, given $g,f\in D$ and $t\in[0,1]$, define a function $h$ such that $h(x)=(1-t)\,f(x)+t\,g(x)$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. Then, clearly, $h(x)\leq h(y)$ whenever $x\leq y$, so $h\in D$. Is this an acceptable way of showing convexitivity? What about closeness?

The space $C^r[0,1]$ is endowed with the norm $||f||=\max_{t\in[0,1]}|f(t)|$.

Comment: Are your $f$ starting out as $C^r?$  Because otherwise I don't see how just being non-decreasing gets you that!  Other than that,  it looks sound to me for convexity.  You could try sequential closure since its a metric space,  show that a convergent sequence of $f_n in D$ implies $f\in D$

Comment: You need to describe the metric/topology in which you are working.

Comment: Alan: The function $f$ is said to be continuous in the exercise.

Comment: Prahlad Vaidyanathan: I forgot about that. It's edited now.